# Running an update query on two large tables

Tags: sql, azure-sql-database

I have a 5 large tables in Azure SQL database. I matched two of those tables to the other 3 via a sql query with a complex WHERE caluse. Now I need to update the two tables with the corresponding fields from the remaining 3 tables. My question is what would be the best way to do that? I am going to use the WHERE clause from my select in the update query, so that's settled, but when I run the select on the whole database, without filtering on specific records, it take forever, literally as the tables are large - couple million records each. So I was wondering if anyone could give me some pointers on what would be the best way to run the update without my connection timing out or anything else happening? SSIS package? updating via some application? Any useful input would be very appreciated

Comment: are indexes defined on the columns in the WHERE clause?

Comment: nope, just primary and foreign keys. Where clause actually uses all of the columns to some extent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How big of the tables you are talking about and what is the Service level objective for that? Upgrade to V12, assuming you have the room to grow, scale up to the maximum SKU, create any missing indexes so that your query runs fast, and run your update query. Once it is succeeded then scale down. Make sure you set the command timeout is infinity.

Answer (score 0):

A few ideas, first if you have a local sql server you can download the backpac file using the [Azure Import/Export service](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/hh335292.aspx), make the changes you need locally then upload them.

If you don't have the ability to use a local machine, you could use pagination with persistence to get around the time out. I'd suggest using offset fetch and a non-temporary work table that you'll delete after you're completed. something along the lines of:

```
declare @RowsToBeUpdated bigint = /* Your required row count */
declare @IterationsCompleted bigint = (select isnull(max(iteration), 0) from Worktable)  
Declare @batchsize bigint = 100000 /* or whatever won't fail, remember that offset fetch will get slow on the backend */
Declare @RowsCompleted bigint = @IterationsCompleted * @batchsize

while @RowsCompleted < @RowsToBeUpdated
begin
  begin transaction
    Update a
    set a.value = a.othervalue
    from thetable a
      inner join (select primarykey from thetable order by primarykey offset @RowsCompleted fetch next @batchsize rows only)
    set @IterationsCompleted = @IterationsCompleted +1
    insert into worktable (select @IterationsCompleted as iteration)
    set @RowsCompleted = @RowsCompleted + @batchsize
  commit transaction
end
```

You'll need to create the work table prior to running this. Anyway, that will loop through the data, and thanks to the transaction wrapper, you won't have any partial commits, so if it times out, you'll be ok. It's also set up so you can just press f5 again to pick up where you left off. However as I mentioned above, offset fetch will suck on the back end so be reasonable with your batch size.

All in all I think the backpac idea is the better one, but soemtimes we don't have all of the tools we need.